# Haskell Tree Traverse Confused

Tags: haskell, recursion, types, tree

I'm very new to haskell and I just can't seem to understand this code:

```
data Tree a = Empty | Leaf a | Node a (Tree a) (Tree a)

-- animals tree 
animals :: Tree String
animals = Node "elephant"
              (Node "bat"
                   (Leaf "aardvark")
                   (Node "cow"
                        (Leaf "chicken")
                         Empty))
              (Node "hare"
                   (Node "fox"
                         Empty
                         (Leaf "goat"))
                   (Leaf "jackal"))
```

Specifically, creating that data type its more complex than simple data types I attempted in class. The animals function creates the tree but how does it utilize that type to do so?

Then traversing it with this function:

```
traverse :: (Tree a) -> [a]
traverse Empty = []
traverse (Leaf x) = [x] --leaf returns list of 1 item
traverse (Node x left_sub_tree right_sub_tree) =
 (traverse left_sub_tree) ++
  [x] ++
 (traverse right_sub_tree)
```

I'm not sure how this code works, probably because I'm not sure how that data type allows us  to make trees. What I can't see is basically the "links" beteen the type creates and how this algorithm uses those function types to create a tree.

Help to understand this would be incredible, thanks!

Comment: One more question - in the traverse function why does it take a "(Tree a)" with an argument "a" and brackets? I've never seen functions taking arguments such as this (its usually just one word).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The data type defines a tree recursively. A tree is composed of cells, each of which can be either "Empty", a "Leaf", or a "Node". The "Node" case has 2 children which are trees as well, this is the recursive definition. The idea is that a tree can either be empty, or a single element, or a single element attached to two other trees.

The `traverse` code also works recursively. If it encounters the empty tree, it returns an empty list. If it encounters a single element, it returns it. If it encounters a "Node", then it runs recursively for the two subtrees, and then combines the results with the `++` operator.

Comment: Thank you that explained it perfectly

Comment: @darkphoton There's an up arrow you can use on answers and questions with the tooltip "This answer is helpful". Maybe you'd like to click it on this answer.